# Firemonkey Android Threading

Tags: firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle, delphi-10.1-berlin

I am running a Thread to do some looped tasks. but there is a problem while doing the tasks and if the app switched The Thread getting very slow and there is huge delay in the tasks to be done any idea why the thread get slower if the app switched ?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve) demonstrating the issue in action.